# how to get dropdown's selected valueusing jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

i want to get the selected value from dropdownlist using jquery or javascript. Please help me

Comment: What technology are you using (i.e. PHP, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, etc.) to generate the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getDropDownList1Value()
    {
        var SelectedVal = $('#< %=<strong>DropDownList1.ClientID %>').val();
        return SelectedVal;
    }
```

If you want to get its selected text the try this

```
$('#drop :selected').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
$("#ddlID").change(function(){
console.log($(this).val());
});

});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ah2Y8/

Comment: Pretty sure this fails in ASP.NET WebForms.

Comment: if he sets the client id mode then the id can be predicted or he can use the class insted of id

Comment: Fair enough. Might be worth mentioning that in your answer. :]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this via jquery is  give the

```
<select ID="Whatever">
```

element an ID then call a function onblur or onsubmit

```
function whatever() { alert($("#Whatever").val()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal `.val()` method will get you the selected value of the dropdown, and the `.text()` method will get you the selected text. The problem you will run into with ASP.NET using WebForms is that the server tags, when generated, contain long concatenated IDs that don't match the ID you specify in the markup. So, your selectors have to be tweaked as @raman shows you above: inject the client ID into the jQuery selector using a server tag. Then the selector will function as normal:

```
// if you're going to reference it a bunch of times, create an object reference
var $ddl = $('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>'); 

var selectedvalue = $ddl.val();
var selectedtext = $ddl.text();
```

HTH.